# Do we have any release guide/SOP for new release of a substrate project?

Tags: polkadot, polkadot-launch

I Want to release my substrate chain. I just want to know that is there anyone has any release guide/ SOP/process which we can follow during release.

For example:
What do we need to document about the release?
version bumping
storage migration
other stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various methods of releasing. It may be helpful for you to look at parachain teams in the ecosystem and see how they are doing their releases - look at their github.